# How to embed a calendar on an Android app?

Tags: android, calendar, widget, embed

I would like to embed a calendar inside my android application... I have seen several open source application, but are not what I would like to have.

Does someone have any suggestion on how to embed it?

Or maybe a good application of a calendar to embed?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not trigger the built-in calendar activities via Intents? Best of both worlds.

Comment: I would like to maintain the layout of my app and stay in the application.... is it possibile?

Comment: Yes it's possible it's just lots of work. I wrote a simple calendar app and an article about it, it's open source, https://market.android.com/details?id=net.jimblackler.quickcalendar http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151 http://svn.jimblackler.net/jimblackler/trunk/workspace/QuickCalendar/